# Can connect to postgres through localhost without password but not through 127.0.0.1. Why?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I have Kubuntu 14.10 desktop with PostgreSQL 9.4 database installed.
I have changed the password of the `postgres` user in the database by executing the SQL:

```
ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'password';
```

And I can connect to DB server by `psql -h localhost -U postgres -W` and giving that password *but* I can also connect without a password requirement by simply `psql -h localhost -U postgres`.

On the other hand, if I run `psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres` it prompts me for the password set before.

What is the difference between the `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` hosts and their login method? Where is it set? I see no `localhost`-related entries in the `pg_hba.conf` file.

Comment: Do you have a .pgpass file?

Comment: Yes. When I googled about it, I didn't find anything about this file. It actually answers my question.

As I see, pgadmin3 created this file when I entered connection details there (and I was curious where does pgadmin store password… didn't look for it, though).

If you post this as a proper answer, I'll accept it as correct.

Comment: Another difference is that `localhost` resolves to `::1` on some systems, or to another IPv6 equivalent, or to several addresses. Any of these means that `127.0.0.1` will not match in `pg_hba.conf`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The behavior you see *might* be caused by a password file. The password file is conventionally named ~/.pgpass on Unix systems, but a different filename can be given through the PGPASSFILE environmental variable.

I think a password file that contains a line for "localhost", but does *not* contain a line for "127.0.0.1" will show the behavior you're seeing. My own ~/.pgpass file contains this line.

```
localhost:*:*:postgres:password
```

Here's what happens when I try to connect just like you did.

```
$ psql -h localhost -U postgres
psql (9.3.5)
SSL connection (cipher: DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits: 256)
Type "help" for help.

sandbox=# \q
$ psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres
Password for user postgres:
```

Adding the line `127.0.0.1:*:*:postgres:password` to ~/.pgpass lets me log in using 127.0.0.1 and no password.

```
$ psql -h 127.0.0.1 -U postgres
psql (9.3.5)
SSL connection (cipher: DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, bits: 256)
Type "help" for help.

sandbox=#
```